# Why I am I getting error = 2 no such file or directory for ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, terminal, processbuilder

I was recently making a program that gave command line inputs using ProcessBuilder but whenever I run my command I am getting this error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "convert" (in directory "/Users/me/Downloads/SpritesFront"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at Downloader.uncompressImage(Downloader.java:32)
    at Main.main(Main.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:319)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:250)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 3 more
```

This is the code that I am using to run the command:

```
public void uncompressImage (String name, boolean back, String path) {

        String b = "";  

        if (back) {

            b = "-back";

        }

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();

        String[] args = new String[] {"convert" , name + b + ".gif", "-coalesce", name + b + ".gif"};

        try {
            pb.directory(new File(path));
            pb.command(args);
            Process process = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And this is where I am calling the method:

```
for (String element : allNames) {

    myDownloader.uncompressImage(element, false, "/Users/me/Downloads/SpritesFront");

}
```

And `allNames` is an array that holds the names of the files that I am trying to uncompress.

Does anyone know what is causing the error message?

Edit: If anyone was wondering the convert command is an ImageMagick command I have installed in my computer through Homebrew

Comment: My immediate guess would be that `name + b + ".gif"` does not resolve to a filename in the directory `/Users/me/Downloads/SpritesFront`. I'd suggest to print out the values of your `args` before you use them so you see what's happening `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args))`. Also, you may need to point to the full path where convert is installed in the first arg, like "/home/scripts/convert".

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried your first solution but the args that are being printed match the file names of those on my computer so it isn't that. For the second thing you said I have no idea where to locate where convert is installed because homebrew installed ImageMagick for me. Is there a way I could locate that to try and see if it works from there? Also when you say first arg do you mean to replace the convert arg with the location of it or just add an arg before convert with the location?